# How to draw a side-by-side plot mentioned in "Graphical Display as an Aid to Analysis"

Tags: r, data-visualization, anova, boxplot, exploratory-data-analysis

Emerson, J. D. (1991) Graphical Display as an Aid to Analysis, in *Fundamentals of Exploratory Analysis of Variance* (eds D. C. Hoaglin, F. Mosteller and J. W. Tukey), John Wiley & Sons, Inc., Hoboken, NJ, USA. [doi: 10.1002/9780470316832.ch8](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9780470316832.ch8)

There describes side-by-side plots of effects and residuals...

I think it's a nice idea for exploratory analysis, but don't know how to draw it..

(The usual side-by-side boxplot is good for one-way analysis but when it gets to two way, it's too complicated to see main effects and interactions...)

Does anyone know how?

Here's some example from the excellent book "A First Course in Design and Analysis of Experiments", which is available on web!!!

[image: one-way]
[image: more complicated setting]

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, any chance you could describe it more.

Comment: It would be totally awesome if you could scan the graphic in question and show it, so we can tell you how to do it or something similar.

Comment: I don't have access to that volume at the moment, but if you provide a little more detail, we can tell you how to make it. Specifically, do you want 2 figures side-by-side, or several boxplots in the same figure? "Residuals" is pretty self-explanatory, but do you also want boxplots for the main effects & interactions? I would think a line plot would be better.

Comment: The entire book is online under a Creative Commons license (http://users.stat.umn.edu/~gary/Book.html)

Comment: One weakness of this plot is that the effects are presented as point estimates, but you really want to see confidence intervals.

Comment: @JackTanner, the point of this plot is to see if there are main effects or interaction effects. From a simple F-test, you can't tell which means are different or by how much. If we see the point estimates of effects and residual on the same scale, we can get an idea of the effect sizes we are dealing with. But, I think it's a great idea to put CIs and residuals side by side! Anyhow, the point, I think, is to think of effects relative to residuals, much like effect sizes! And I think plotting only effects is not as helpful unless we consider errors they might contain, and I think interaction pl

Comment: @JackTanner, that book looks interesting, but it is not *Fundamentals of Exploratory Analysis of Variance*.

Comment: This is really a comment in response to Jack Tanner's comment above. It should not be put as an answer. If it doesn't fit into 1 comment, due to the length constraints, split it into 2 comments, don't put it as an answer.

Comment: @gung, you're right, it's the other book cited in the question; the side-by-side plot idea is the same.

Answer (score 2):

On the topic of visualising ANOVA output, how about this. See here for motivation: http://www.acase.org/rpruzek/anovagraphic.pdf And here for a very basic explanation of the various parts of the figure: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/382638/Brian-Danielak-granova.pdf and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/382638/DanielakGranovaRevision20110714.pdf

And see here for the `R` package that made this figure (using `ggplot2`): https://github.com/briandk/granovaGG

[image]