# How to utilize the result of aov function?

Tags: r, data-visualization, anova

Based on the responses from the question [How to draw a side-by-side plot mentioned in "Graphical Display as an Aid to Analysis"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28086/how-to-draw-a-side-by-side-plot-mentioned-in-graphical-display-as-an-aid-to-ana), I am considering implementing the function myself.  The problem is that I don't know how to utilize the result of `aov()` function.  I have to see how many factors there are, the names of factors, what are their main effects and interaction effects, etc.  I can get residuals from `aov(y~x)$residuals`.  I consulted the documentation for `aov()`, but I still have no clue how to do this.  There must be some other way much complex than something like `t.test(x,y)$p.value`.

Would you help me?

Comment: aov has a strange way of indexing it's information. Is "summary(aov1)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]]" what you're after?

Comment: Are you opening a new account w/ every new question? You have rep=1 again here, vs. 36 at your other question. Please maintain *only one* account. This is really best for you, as well (all your questions would be grouped together, it would be easier to get messages people leave for you, etc.)

Comment: I did some editing here. However, I can't make any sense of your last sentence, you may want to rework it somewhat to make it clearer. Also, this question seems to be only about how to code / work w/ `R`, not about any statistical concepts per se; it may be more appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Comment: KH Kim, I've merged your three accounts (I already did this two days ago)--thanks to @gung. Please register your account once for all.

Comment: Sorry if I bothered you. Anyhow I not interested in building up my reputation. I just wanted to leave comments or questions. And I couldn't see add comments button or I always had to log in with name and email. I used the same email and the name so I don't know what's wrong... I may have had to use "guest" account if it exists or I may better go anonymous.

Comment: @KHKim You're not bothering me. You just need to register your account (see the [login page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/login)). Then you'll be able to get system-wide notifications, leave comment and edit your questions, etc. See [Do I have to log in or create an account?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) in our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 5):

The `str` function will show you the structure of any object, including the results from `aov`.  Some values of interest (such as p-values) are not in the aov object, but in the summary object from `summary(aov.object)` (run `str` on that as well).  Some statistics will be a column in a matrix (the p-value is a column in the coefficient matrix of the summary object).

The aov object has an additional complexity in that it can be a list of aov objects (due to possible nesting structures, each level of nesting producing an object in the list).  You might want to examine the code of other functions that use aov objects to see how they access the parts and what they do with them.